# PHPUnit not working with netbeans 7.2.1

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I have just upgraded to netbeans 7.2.1 and phpunit is not working. I get the error:-

> Cannot run program C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit-skelgen": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application" when I try to generate PHPUnit tests.

The only thing I can think of is that I seem to have a 64 bit version of netbeans installed - could this be the problem?

If so, can anyone point me to a 32 bit version, because I couldn't see one on the website?

Comment: NetBeans is Java: it's exactly the same binary for all platforms (Win 32, Win 64, Unix, Linux, MacOS...). Perhaps you mean the JRE? - Can you run `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit-skelgen` from the command line?

Comment: Ah OK, I just thought it was 64 bit because it was in the "program files" folder and not the "program files x86" folder. I am able to run skelgen from the command line - I get a screen with all the skelgen options.

Comment: Well, yes, there're a few native utilities like the installer or the *.exe launcher, I forgot about that.

Comment: Could this affect the running of PHPUnit then?

Comment: I found the solution. Netbeans had automatically configured the skelgen path but did not put ".bat" on the end of it, so it was just "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit-skelgen". This should work, but didn't. I added a ".bat" to the end so it looks like "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit-skelgen.bat" and now it works!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. Stack Overflow encourages so.

Comment: It won't allow me to answer my own question for another 4 hours apparently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Netbeans had automatically configured the skelgen path but did not put ".bat" on the end of it, so it was just "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit-skelgen". This should work, but didn't. I added a ".bat" to the end so it looks like "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit-skelgen.bat" and now it works!